# iPhone 6s: apps greyed out after restore from another phone's backup

Tags: applications, backup, restore, iphone

So I had an iPhone 5 for a few years.

I bought a 6s recently and after restoring a backup from my iPhone 5.

**After the restore, most of my apps are greyed out.**

When I tap an icon, **the name of the app switches to "Waiting" but nothing seems to happens.**

On top of that, it **seems like my passwords have been lost**. For example, I've got 6 email addresses on the phone and when I open the "Mail" app it asks me to enter the credentials again, I'm not sure if it's related.

NB: I do not use iCloud at all.

I looked it up on the internet and already tried the following:

- Restore again
- Resync everything
- Log out and log back in my iTunes / App Store account
- Reboot the device

NB: I know it's possible to get my apps back by using the "Purchased Items" from the App Store but **I do not want to delete my apps as I do not want to loose the data from them.**

Comment: If you still have the 5S, first thing I'd do is a new **Encrypted** backup & restore from that. Passwords are not saved if the backup is not encrypted.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the suggestion. However I don't have the 5 anymore. So I guess I can give up on the passwords.

Comment: Yes, they are only in encrypted backups, for security. Your apps should gradually come to you over your data connection, probably wifi/non-metered connection

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried quickly on my WiFi yesterday but it didn't work I'll try again tonight and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting normally means the phone is doing something with the app store. The iPhone 6s is larger then the iPhone 5, so therefor the apps that work on a 5 probably won't work on a 6, or at least they will look a bit weird. Leave the phone connected to the internet and let it do its thing, if after a while the apps are still "Waiting" then the only other reason for this is, the apps just aren't compatible.

Comment: Well I'll give it a try tonight with my home WiFi and see how it looks tomorrow morning I'll let you know

Comment: Once on WiFi it started to download back the missing apps. On top of that I had some issues because I use two different app users to download my apps (a french and an australian one)

Comment: Glad I could help!